# Java - multiple requests from two WebContainer threads

Tags: java, soap, timeout, websphere

We are testing a sub-system timeout of 150 seconds.  So in my application, the first SOAP request is sent.  Then 60 seconds later, another request is sent.  My question is where is the other request coming from.  It's new thread yet, but the client code has no re-try mechanism.  This is running on WebSphere 6.  These are snippets from the logs:

```
2011-01-18 16:16:32.696 EST [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG content  <> << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"

2011-01-18 16:17:32.591 EST [WebContainer : 2] DEBUG content  <> << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
```

As you can see the same reqeust is called, from a different WebContainer almost one minute apart.  How can I find where the 2nd request is coming from?  What should I check in WebSphere to debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealt with this issue just a couple of weeks ago. The HTTP Plugins of WebSphere have a default time-out setting of 60 seconds. If your thread still hasn't returned after 60 seconds, the request will be reissued (I believe by the HTTP Server, but not sure). Hence the second WebContainer thread processing the request.

You can set the plugin time to > 150 seconds in order to test your case. Set the **ServerIOTimeout** custom property in the "Plug-In Properties" page of the web server definition in the WebSphere admin console. Set to 0 for an infinite wait time.

This works on both WAS6.1 and WAS7, I guess you can find out if it does on WAS6.

Comment: Encountered this scenario for the first time.   I thought the user requested the expensive web resource again and again, based on application log.  But it turned out to be that it was the web server!.  WebSphere http access log made it clear the request came in just once.    WARNING : This could quickly escalate into taking down the system (Affecting availability), if there is a poison request (expensive request that ties up limited resources [Connection from pool]), then that request is faithfully replayed by the web server putting more load and depleting more of the limited resource.