# JBoss 5.1 Servlet repeats request after 60 seconds

Tags: servlets, jboss5.x

We have a servlet that accepts requests and performs certain actions on external systems.  Many times these external systems respond slowly and the requests take longer than 60 seconds.  In the log we notice that exactly after 60 seconds a new request is made to the servlet (with the same post parameters) as long as the client is still connected.

Googling found that the same is reported on other App Servers such as Glassfish etc.  The reason seems to be that after a timeout of 60 seconds the servlet or the web container are timing out the call and repeating the request.  Note that this seems to be a servlet or container initiated refresh and not really posted from the client.  Way to avoid this is to apparently increase the timeout. (Read more here on a similar issue:  [Java - multiple requests from two WebContainer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753276/java-multiple-requests-from-two-webcontainer-threads))

I increased the connectionTimeout in the deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml to 120000 (2 minutes) but the call repeats exactly after 60 seconds still.

Any idea how to increase the timeout or to avoid this behaviour in JBoss?

Thanks
Srini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  The problem was not to do with JBoss at all.  Our JBoss servers run on Amazon EC2 instances and are behind an ELB load balancer.  The AWS ELB load balancer timesout after every 60 seconds of idle time and resubmits the request.